# Построить большой выпуклый многоугольник

Tags: алгоритм

Надо построить выпуклый многоугольник с количеством вершин в несколько тысяч или десятков тысяч. Сначала я придумал такой алгоритм: генерируется множество уникальных точек (около 90000 точек), для них строится выпуклая оболочка, которая и будет многоугольником. Но у такого многоугольника получается слишком мало вершин: больше 21 ни разу не получилось.

Какой еще алгоритм можно придумать? Выстроить все точки в ряд кроме одной, одну поставить над ними, и использовать такой треугольник?

Comment: Правильный `n`-угольник? Точки легко считаются через угол и радиус.

Comment: Или просто `n` различных точек на окружности, задаются `n` углами от 0 до 2π.

Comment: Я сначала хотел накидать на плоскость много корней из единицы большой степени, но подумал, что будут проблемы с точностью десятичных дробей, которые получатся почти одинаковые.

Comment: Ну, это и есть правильный n-угольник, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Да, только координаты точек на окружности почти не будут отличаться.

Comment: Ну, заметьте, что это самый лучший, как бы самый выпуклый многоугольник. Остальные будут хуже, у них точки будут ещё ближе.

Comment: А если в полярной системе координат точкам дать очень большой радиус, чтобы они были далеко друг от друга? Хотя, может быть, можно нагенерировать корней из единицы, потом умножить их координаты на большое число и округлить до целых?

Comment: Думаю, результаты отличаться по сути не будут. Попробуйте!

Comment: Да, последний способ отличный.

Comment: Тогда опубликую как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте накидать `n` различных случайных точек на окружность. Для этого достаточно выбрать `n` случайных углов в промежутке [0, 2π), и взять точки (`x0 + r cos phi[i]`, `y0 + r sin phi[i]`). Не забудьте отсортировать углы перед этим, чтобы получить вершины в правильном порядке.